# Private videos visible in 'view profile as public'?

Tags: google-plus

For some reason I can see private videos in the videos tab in my profile when I use "view profile as public" mode.

Why is this? Are they really public despite being private?

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that private videos are visible to people who don't have permission to view it. Chances are either the "view as public" feature doesn't work quite right or the videos are actually pubic.

The best way to be sure is to use private/incognito mode of your browser or sign out of Google before viewing your video tab.